# KIE workbench build did not update process definitions

Tags: jbpm, kie-workbench

I've defined a bunch of new processes with KIE Workbench, which have been committed but not pushed to a remote. When I try to re-build in the workbench for the purpose of testing the processes the build says that it's successful, but the new process definitions do not appear in the workbench.

I am very new to this tool so am at a loss as to why this is happening. Anyone have any ideas of why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the deployment section and un deploy the deployment unit before building and deploying the same version again. If you change the version of your project and processes you will be able to see all the different versions in the process definition list.
HTH